# Controller not called the second time in ionic app

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, controller

In one of my apps built using Ionic framework, I have a few template files that are used to display content on click of the 'Next' button. However, on certain instances I want to use the same template but with different data (-else part of the if-else condition in the below js code). The template displays the correct data the very first time it is loaded. However the next I hit the 'next' button, there is no call that is made to the controller(AerodynamicCtrl) and I am getting the same data (if part of the condition) again. Also I read about ion-view but I have not used it for my code. Could someone please help me and suggest what I am doing wrong here? Thanks in advance.

my code below -

html code - index.html

```
<ion-content>
 <div class="list card">
    <div data-id='{{q_no}}' class="item item-divider custom-question-title">
        {{question_info.text}}
    </div>
    <div data-ng-include="getQuestionTemplate()"></div>
 </div>
</ion-content>
```

getQuestionTemplate() in the above code snippet fetches my template based on some condition and renders the below file

templates/ion-aero.html

```
<div data-ng-controller="AerodynamicCtrl" class="spritespin" ng-init="init_aerodynamic_activity()"></div>
```

JS code

```
app.controller("AerodynamicCtrl", ["$scope", "$localStorage", "$fileLogger", AerodynamicCtrl]);

function AerodynamicCtrl($scope, $localStorage, $fileLogger){

    $scope.init_aerodynamic_activity = function(){

        if($scope.question_info.category == 1){
            $('.spritespin').spritespin({
                // generate an array of image urls. This is a helper function that takes a {frame} placeholder
                source: SpriteSpin.sourceArray('img/aero/{frame}.png', {
                    frame: [1,52] // this ramge of numbers is interpolated into the {frame} placeholder
                }),
                width: 480, // Specify the display width and height of the frame. // Optionally the size of the container can be defined with CSS.
                height: 327,
                responsive: true
            });

        } else {
            $('.spritespin').spritespin({
                // source: 'lib/threesixty-slider/assets/panorama.jpg',
                source: 'img/aero/panorama.jpg',
                width: 600, // this sets the width of the display. The panorama image must be larger than the below width
                height: 300,
                // select the modules
                mods: [
                    'drag',  // change frame on mouse drag
                    'ease',  // enable the easing module. this will ease out the animation after mouse release, instead of a hard stop
                    'panorama' // the panorama display module
                ]
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Either remove the view from being cached on parent `ion-view` tag:

```
<ion-view view-title="Title" cache-view="false"></ion-view>
```

Or use one of Ion view events:

```
$scope.$on("$ionicView.enter", function(event, data){
   $scope.init_aerodynamic_activity();
});
```

Second option is better as the view is cached and you have more control over the events as described here:
http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionView/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to put in your routing the property cache:false?

like:

```
 $stateProvider
        .state('app', {
            url: '/app',
            abstract: true,
            templateUrl: 'templates/menu.html',
            controller: 'AppCtrl'
        })
        .state('app.products', {
            url: '/products',
            views: {
                'menuContent': {
                    templateUrl: 'templates/product/tab-products.html',
                    controller: 'ProductsCtrl',
                    cache:false, //this force IONIC to re call the controller
                    controllerAs: 'prod'
                }
            }
        })
```

Comment: Yes, I have the below snippet but it does not work -                       app.config(function($stateProvider){
 $stateProvider
        .state('App', {
            url: '/',
            cache:false,
            abstract: true,
            templateUrl: 'templates/ion-aero.html',
            controller: 'AerodynamicCtrl'
    })
});

Comment: be carefully .. abstract: true .. means that it is not a real url / path ..so try to remove it